# HTML Datatable : Table row is going outside

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable, html-table

I have data table.
when I resize it below **860px** then It is going outside table. I have total **8** table header but **8th** header is going outside the table when I resize the window.

[image: Here is the Image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><table ui-jq="dataTable"  class="table table-striped b-t b-b dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
                    <thead>
                        <tr role="row" class="font-bold text-center no_border">
                            <th style="width: 150px;" class="sorting_asc no_border" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descendig" aria-sort="ascending">Name</th>
                            <th style="width: 150px;" class="sorting no_border" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending">Emai Id</th>
                            <th style="width: 100px;" class="sorting no_border" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending">Seq No</th>
                            <th style="width: 200px;" class="sorting no_border" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending">Ticket Type</th>
                            <th style="width: 150px;" class="sorting no_border" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending">Amount</th>
                            <th style="width: 50px;" class="sorting no_border" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending">Paid</th>
                            <th style="width: 150px;" class="sorting no_border" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending">Order Date</th>
                            <th style="width: 150px;" class="sorting no_border" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending">Payment Order</th>
                            <!--<th style="width: 120px;" class="sorting no_border" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending">Payment</th>-->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td class="sorting_1">
                            <img src="images/image.png" class="img-circle vertical_align_middle" width="35" height="35"><span class="margin_left_30">Saumil</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>saumil12346678@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>VGA 1001</td>
                        <td>Lark - Super Early Bird</td>
                        <td>INR 1000</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                        <td>30th November 2016</td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Refund</button> </td>
                    </tr>

                    </table></div></div>
                    </div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLmah2r5/)

Any help would be great.
Thank You.

Comment: The data reaches its minimum width that it can and then jumps out of the table, I have experienced this before you will need to define a min-width for your table or enable a horizontal scroll.

Comment: it's because your table width can't cover total width of your <td>. Try to remove fixed width for <td>. And give scroll to overflowX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fixed the width of your table to 1200px and all your th to 150px so no matter the size of your screen the size of your table won't change

Since you are using bootstrap you should put your table inside a div and giv the div a class **table-responsive**

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

[**See documentation here**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)

Comment: oh yeah... got it.. actually I have used it in my code but don't know some of my colleague has removed it.. Thank You so much ... :) accepting your answer in 2 min.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)